# Error 1206 when deleting records from a table

Tags: mysql

I am using the following command to delete records from a table. Had initial success with 1m records for 9 runs , but then start experiencing problems with error code `1206` even when deleting 1000 records:

```
DELETE FROM PD where `period` = "201201" limit 1000;

Records in table            180,005,889
Initial Records with period =”201201”:   19,861,544
Remaining records to delete:        9,929,472
```

Comment: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1546

Comment: increase the innodb_buffer_pool_size variable in /etc/my.cnf (apparently)